# Use a Selector instead of "this" in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Maybe it's a silly question. But I really can't understand it.

I'm using the Jquery Cycle2. And after some personalization I got a simple problem.
I need to know what is the "Index" of my current slide.

On the plugin's website a found this line of code that perfectly works.

```
$('#cycle-1 .cycle-slide').click(function(){
    var index = $('#cycle-1').data('cycle.API').getSlideIndex(this);
    alert(index);
});
```

It gives me the right index. But I'm trying to catch this Index when another element is clicked. So I can't use the parameter (this).

Then I tried this.

```
$('.anotherelement').click(function(){
    var mycycle = $('#cycle-1 .cycle-slide');
    var index = $('#cycle-1').data('cycle.API').getSlideIndex($(mycycle));
    alert(index);
});
```

It doesn't return my current slide index. It returns "-1". Does anyone knows how I should pass the Object (selector) as a parameter to the getSlideIndex() ?

Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Can you provide fiddle for it?

Comment: `$(mycycle)` -> `mycycle[0]` should make it identical to using `this` instead

Comment: getSlideIndex(mycycle[0]); ?

Comment: I think you can only make this work when ".anotherelement" is a slide. If it is then using "this" should still work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$('.cycle-slideshow').data('cycle.opts').currSlide` to get the current slide index

```
$('.anotherelement').click(function(){
    var index = $('.cycle-slideshow').data('cycle.opts').currSlide;
    var currSliderNum = index+1;
    alert(currSliderNum);
    return false;
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p2khc/)

Comment: You need to change the class name `cycle-slideshow` to your slider `id` or `class name`

Answer (score 0):

In the first piece of code `this` is a DOM element and not a jquery object.  Try this instead:

```
var index = $('#cycle-1').data('cycle.API').getSlideIndex(mycycle[0]);
```

However, presumably, you have multiple `.cycle-slide` elements.  This will just get the first one.  In your first code you have access to a single one since only one was clicked.  You need to decide which one you want to target here.

Comment: Thanks, that was also helpful.